# How do I create an "artificial" redirect on iPad?

Tags: network, ipad

I have a webserver running under the 0.0.0.0 address, bound to a given port - let's call it 8080. By using 0.0.0.0 as the host address, I can successfully access my webserver from the iPad using my computer's network IP (192.168.100.5).

Turns out my server has some redirections pointing to 0.0.0.0:port, and 0.0.0.0 is unknown to my iPad. One idea I had is to make the iPad interpret 0.0.0.0 as 192.168.100.5, but after some thorough research, I couldn't find successful answers on how to do that.

So here I am: **how can I make an iPad, using Safari, to interpret 0.0.0.0 as 192.168.100.5?**

A parallel example would be, every time I access `http://whatever`, I'd like my browser (Safari) to access https://google.com or something.

Answer (score 3):

There's no IP address named 0.0.0.0. Therefore you cannot be running a web server on that address, and that is the reason why your iPad cannot open such an address.

You might be confused because when programming, it is usually possible to specify that you want to bind for example port 8080 on 0.0.0.0. However in that case, 0.0.0.0 is not an address - it is a specific non-address values that means that indicates to the operating system that you want to bind port 8080 on *any* network interface (i.e. on all the IP-addresses on your computer).

The problem here is not with the iPad. Instead you have a misconfiguration on your server that has caused it to send out redirections to 0.0.0.0. Those redirections are invalid in themselves. Ordinarily servers like that are by default setup to redirect to the same IP address that the user accessed the server by initially.